# Java EE Named Query with SUM() is not working

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, db2, jpql, named-query

I've created a simple @NamedQuery:

`@NamedQuery(name = "Etap.findSum", query = "SELECT e.czas FROM Etap e WHERE e.stan=1")`

which is working fine. The field `e.czas` was mapped as an `Integer` and is of type `INTEGER` in DB2 database. Now when I am trying to change it in that way:

`@NamedQuery(name = "Etap.findSum", query = "SELECT SUM(e.czas) FROM Etap e WHERE e.stan=1")`

it fails, and what is more, the editor does not give a hint to choose the filed `e.czas` as a parameter of the query.
When I change the type of the filed `czas` to `int`, the hint is given, but the query still doesn't work (it works when called from IBM Data Studio console).

The method where I call the query is listed below (I always get -1 as a result):

```
public Integer suma(){
        try{
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Etap.findSum");
            Integer suma = (Integer)q.getSingleResult();
            return suma;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: "I always get -1 as a result" means there is an exception. Do yourself a favour and print its stack trace.

Comment: It's probably auto widening to `Long`, to prevent the sum of your integers being too big for the type.  Given the documentation for `SUM(...)` explicitly lists this behavior happening on the db-side, the ORM likely has to follow suit.  If you're really confident that your result can be contained in an int, cast it on the after the sum is calculated.

Comment: @mustaccio you are right, I've been looking into stack trace without try-catch but apparently, I've missed something

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You answer is right, the problem was the cast:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.IntegerCaused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.
The query works perfect with Long as a result, I've also discovered, that using _nativeQuery_ resolve the problem (when casting the result to Integer)

Comment: Actually, I might be wrong.  It said small integer to large integer, which turns out to be short and integer equivalent, respectively.  The rest of the documentation states the type should be unchanged.  So the db is unlikely to be doing it...  Now, the ORM could be casting everything to long just in case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the ORM is auto-widening the result in anticipation of the result turning into a `Long`, and not an `Integer`.
Note that if the source column is a `Short` (equivalent), then[`SUM(...)` widens the result to an `Integer` in all cases](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000765.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.8.0%2F2-9-3-1-11).  The documentation doesn't explicitly mention what happens in the case of an `Integer` source column, but I'd imagine the db auto-widens it in the case the result is sufficiently large.
The ORM then has to account for this potential behavior by making sure it can handle a long - so it casts it to that type, unless the result is specifically stated to be safe (by casting it to `Integer` on the db).